# Como crear app de escritorio con python usando tablas de datos locales?

Tags: python, base-de-datos, interfaz-gráfica, aplicación-escritorio, ciencia-de-datos

Me encuentro desarrollando mi primer programa de python donde estoy precisando crear distintas tablas (historiales.csv) del usuario de forma local. A medida que se va usando el programa, quiero que se creen historiales de acciones que el usuario vaya agregando. Después esas tablas se analizan y se relacionan entre sí.

Supongamos que se le pide al usuario crear una historial de ejercicios fisicos realizados. Quiero que se cree esa tabla y luego con el tiempo el usuario irá agregando los ejercicios realizados en el día.

Por el momento estoy creando las tablas mediante Pandas. Realizo una función que tome algunos datos del usuario y se cree. Luego otra función que permita agregar datos. Otra función que permita modificarlos. Otra que permita eliminar datos y otra que actualice los datos en caso que se hayan agregado datos de fechas previas (que se haya olvidado el usuario).

Siento que es muy poco eficiente esta manera de hacerlo ya que, para agregar y modificar datos, estoy leyendo el dataframe cada vez. Posiblemente valga decir que uno de estos historiales puede llegar a tener 4000 lineas de dato por año en el peor de los casos.

Como pienso crear un programa de escritorio (en principio, luego lo hare para celular), quería saber si hay otra forma de crear estas tablas localmente para que se pueda modificar de manera óptima. También me gustaría saber qué librería me conviene utilizar para realizar el GUI ya que es un programa orientado a la ciencia de datos. Quiero que los datos se puedan agregar y modificar de forma sencilla por el usuario, pudiendo filtrar y escoger las líneas a modificar/eliminar; no sé qué GUI es mejor para realizar un programa así.

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! a ver.. hay muchos errores de conceptos. Primero, estas creando tablas, no bases de datos. una base de datos es un conjunto de tablas, y esas tablas tienen columnas con sus tipos de datos, y en las tablas se guardan registros. Pandas, no es una base de datos. Es una libreria para analizar y procesar datos. (sigue)

Comment: La base de datos, deberia estar creada desde antes. Si tu programa pide datos, tu programa ya sabe que datos pide, entonces no es necesario crear nada. Vas a necesitar seguro mas de una tabla para los datos del usuario. Igual, 4000 filas es nada, en cualquier lenguaje y cualquier formato. Motores de bases de datos hay montones, pero para simplificarte y arrancar, empeza con sqlite. y toda tu pregunta, esta basada en opiniones y va a terminar cerrada (editala usando [edit]). Esta clase de cosas va mejor en el [chat] (cuando tengas suf. reputacion)

Comment: @gbianchi Muchas gracias! Voy a tomar en cuenta tus observaciones.